# Estimating the number of books in the world from randomly chosen overlapping lists

Tags: combinatorics, estimation

Suppose I have lists $L_1 , \dots , L_n$ of, say, books.  Assume further that these are uniformly chosen from the set of all books (probably unrealistic for obvious reasons, and if this assumption can be weakened, I'd be even more impressed).  Suppose these lists are of size $k_1 , \dots , k_n$ and there are $a_{ij}$ books in common with lists $L_i$ and $L_j$ (that is, $|L_i \cap L_j| = a_{ij}$).  How can we best use this data to estimate the total number of books in existence?

The [mark and recapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) method suggests a solution for the case when $n = 2$ as well as a worst-possible way of estimating the total number of books.  Can we do better, though, since we have (supposedly) more than 2 lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a binomial distribution problem where you're trying to deduce the true proportion $\vec{p}$ from the observed proportion $p$. Compile all your lists into one large dataset, fix some degree of confidence $d$ and construct a confidence interval for a proportion.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow.  I don't see the correspondence to the problem.  Will this work if all the lists have drastically different sizes?  Suppose one list has 600 entries and another list has only 50.

Comment: Unless there's a piece of information I'm missing, the lists represent unbiased samples of the distribution. Is this incorrect?